# Installing katoolin on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, bash

Am done installing katoolin on my Ubuntu 20.04 but when I run katoolin, am getting this;

```
"bash: /usr/bin/katoolin: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't quite done installing yet. Looks like you forgot to install a Python2 interpreter: `sudo apt install python2`.

- Older releases of Ubuntu included Python2. That's likely why your instructions did not specify it.

Comment: The new ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support python2.